# Where are ARB_separate_shader_objects functions? (eg glUseProgramStages, glCreateShaderProgramv)

Tags: opengl, glew, opengl-4

I can't seem to be able to find the process address of these functions on my system.  I'm using GLEW 1.9 which has support for everything.  I am loading a 4.3 core profile for my context...  My nVidia drivers are fully up to date.  I downloaded a program called GPU Caps and it shows the extension as available.  Any ideas?

Update -  I had to enable glewExperimental to get it to work.  I thought program separation was core since 4.1.  If there are no insights I will mark this as solved.

Comment: This is not a forum; we don't answer questions in the question itself. If you have an answer, then you should post it *as an answer*. And you don't mark a question "solved"; you *accept* an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I had to enable glewExperimental to get it to work.

Of course you did. GLEW is broken when it comes to loading OpenGL core contexts. You have to turn on that switch to make it work. It's a well-known workaround.

Or you could just use an [OpenGL loading system](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Loading_Library) that *isn't* broken for core (which would be pretty much anything besides GLEW that is still in active development). FYI: I wrote a couple of those.

Comment: This is it, if I make a compatibility context I don't need th experimental flag.